# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.user_agents' | Pytest

Tags: python, pytest

I have an error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lib.user_agents'` during my pytest execution. It was working before I move from a docker image to another.
Here is my project architecture:

```
project/
 |- conftest.py
 |- lib/
 | |- init.py
 | |- user_agents/
 | | | - init.py
 | |- some_other_folders/
 |- test/
```

And here is my `conftest.py` content:

```
pytest_plugins = ("lib", "lib.user_agents")
```

Any help will be welcome!

Comment: Possible typo? lib.user_agent**s** (with an **s**) vs. lib/user_agent (no **s**)

Comment: Thanks, unfortunalty not, it's the https://github.com/selwin/python-user-agents project.

Comment: Can you post the full error traceback?

Answer (score 1):

When I moved from a docker image to another, I forgot to add my project directory to my `$PATHONPATH` environnement variable. To fix it I just had to do:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/my/project
```